# Airflow + Dockeroperator unable to pass mounts / volumes using mounts parameter

Tags: docker, airflow, dockeroperator

I am trying to pass a local directory as a volume to airflow, which in turn is being passed to a dag DockerOperator

my airflow-docker-compose.yaml (in section airflow-common) looks as follows

```
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./input:/opt/airflow/input
    - ./output:/opt/airflow/output
```

In the DAG code, I am trying to pass the mounts parameters as following:

```
eod_price = DockerOperator(
        task_id='run_docker',
        image='alpine',
        api_version='auto',
        command='/bin/touch /output/run_docker_touch.txt',
        auto_remove=True,
        mounts=[
            Mount(source='/opt/airflow/output',
                  target='/app_base/output',
                  type='volume'),
        ],
        mount_tmp_dir=False,
        docker_url='tcp://docker-proxy:2375',
        network_mode='bridge'
    )
```

With this code, I get error:

> Bad Request ("create /opt/airflow/output: "/opt/airflow/output"
> includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only
> "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a
> host directory, use absolute path")

when I change the mounts line from type='volume' to type='bind':

```
mounts=[
            Mount(source='/opt/airflow/output',
                  target='/app_base/output',
                  type='bind'),
        ],
```

the error changes to

> Bad Request ("invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path
> does not exist: /opt/airflow/output")

I did bash into docker007-airflow-scheduler-1, docker007-airflow-triggerer-1, docker007-airflow-webserver-1 , docker007-airflow-worker-1 and in each of the containers I see /opt/airflow/output directory where docker-compose ps output is

```
NAME                            COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
docker007-airflow-init-1        "/bin/bash -c 'funct…"   airflow-init        exited (0)          
docker007-airflow-scheduler-1   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   airflow-scheduler   running (healthy)   8080/tcp
docker007-airflow-triggerer-1   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   airflow-triggerer   running (healthy)   8080/tcp
docker007-airflow-webserver-1   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   airflow-webserver   running (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
docker007-airflow-worker-1      "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   airflow-worker      running (healthy)   8080/tcp
docker007-docker-proxy-1        "socat TCP4-LISTEN:2…"   docker-proxy        running             0.0.0.0:2376->2375/tcp
docker007-postgres-1            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   postgres            running (healthy)   5432/tcp
docker007-redis-1               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   redis               running (healthy)   6379/tcp
```

My end goal is that I want the output of my dockerized python app that writes to /app_base/output(this echo command is only example) to be visible in local output directory

Answer (score 5):

ok, finally figured it out.
The source path is **not** of the airflow volume mount directory but your original source directory from where the airflow application was started.

The following code worked

```
pre_step = DockerOperator(
    task_id='pre_step_docker',
    image='alpine',
    api_version='auto',
    command='/bin/touch /output/run_docker_touch.txt',
    auto_remove=True,
    mounts=[
        Mount(source='/Users/me/Documents/Python/GitHub/docker-learn/docker007/output',
              target='/output',
              type='bind'),
    ],
    mount_tmp_dir=False,
    docker_url='tcp://docker-proxy:2375',
    network_mode='bridge'
)
```

In other words, the volumes mounted in docker-compose are *not required*. I have commented out what I had added

```
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
#    - ./input:/opt/airflow/input
#    - ./output:/opt/airflow/output
```

However, this hard coded path was also very ugly for me, so I added new variables in docker-compose file (in airflow-common --> environment section)

```
APP_INPUT_DIR: ${PWD}/input
APP_OUTPUT_DIR: ${PWD}/output
```

and updated my code as follows:

```
pre_step = DockerOperator(
    task_id='pre_step_docker',
    image='alpine',
    api_version='auto',
    command='/bin/touch /output/run_docker_touch.txt',
    auto_remove=True,
    mounts=[
        Mount(source=os.getenv("APP_OUTPUT_DIR"),
              target='/output',
              type='bind'),
    ],
    mount_tmp_dir=False,
    docker_url='tcp://docker-proxy:2375',
    network_mode='bridge'
)
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Thanks for documenting your solution! I could not figure it out myself.

Comment: You are a saint and I can't thank you enough.